# Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

This warning came out when I trained my model. Since I used a custom tensorflow op, the training didn't work and the error is:

```
2018-08-13 19:56:33.736226: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:660] Executor failed to create kernel. Not found: No registered '_CopyFromGpuToHost' OpKernel for CPU devices compatible with node swap_out_training/SGD/gradients/pyramid_roi_align_1/CropResize_grad/CropResizeGradBoxes_2 = _CopyFromGpuToHost[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc@traini...radBoxes_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](pyramid_roi_align_1/strided_slice/_343)
    .  Registered:  device='GPU'

     [[Node: swap_out_training/SGD/gradients/pyramid_roi_align_1/CropResize_grad/CropResizeGradBoxes_2 = _CopyFromGpuToHost[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc@traini...radBoxes_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](pyramid_roi_align_1/strided_slice/_343)]]
```

I think it was caused by `tf.gather()` and `tf.gather_nd()` in my loss function, since for another model which doesn't have those two functions it can run.

> So my question is, am I right? If that so, how to solve this problem?